# Hackerrank/ 30 days of code/ day 8

Tags: c#

Please help me understand,
I am currently participating in 30 days of code. I am on day 8 which is about Dictionaries in C#. I go to run my code but hackerrank shows a fatal error. However, when i run my code in visual studio everything works as it is supposed to. here is my code. Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
class Solution {
    static void Main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution */
        int N, phoneNum;
        string name;


        N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Dictionary<string, int> phoneBook = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for(int index = 0; index < N; ++index)
        {
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            phoneNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            phoneBook.Add(name, phoneNum);
        }

        for(int index = 0; index < N; ++index)
        {
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            if(phoneBook.ContainsKey(name) == true)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}",name, phoneBook[name]);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Not found");
        }


    }
}
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str, NumberStyles options, System.NumberBuffer& number
```

Comment: Are you sure it is expecting C# code.  There's comments in your code that say "Read input from STDIN ...STDOUT".  Sounds like C++.

Comment: So we are supposed to guess what the "fatal error" is?

Comment: what error you get

Comment: Run it in Visual Studio instead of Hacker Rank, you can debug the issue yourself

Comment: My program runs fine in visual studios. here is everything plus error code.

Comment: Unhandled Exception:
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
  at System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str, NumberStyles options, System.NumberBuffer& number,

Comment: Seems clear that the input they're using to test is different from the input you test with. IE: they're giving you a string that isn't a number.

Comment: I don't get why people always downvote valid questions.  The site works similar to any other other IDE, super confused on how to read STDIN, but either ways, less hate in the StackOverflow community please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your responses. in my ignorance i didn't realize that the "key" and the value was inputted as one string. However, logically that is dumb. I would have two variables specific to key and value. Here is my updated code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
class Solution {
    static void Main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution */
        int N;
        string dumbAssInput, name, phoneNum;


        N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Dictionary<string, string> phoneBook = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for(int index = 0; index < N; ++index)
        {
            dumbAssInput = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] keyAndValue = dumbAssInput.Split(' ');
            name = keyAndValue[0];
            phoneNum = keyAndValue[1];
            phoneBook.Add(name, phoneNum);
        }

        for(int index = 0; index < N; ++index)
        {
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            if(phoneBook.ContainsKey(name) == true)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}",name, phoneBook[name]);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Not found");
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Dictionary<string,string> phoneBook = new Dictionary<string,string>();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var names = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    phoneBook.Add(names[0], names[1] );
}

string name = Console.ReadLine();
do
{ 
    string printValue = "Not found";
    if (phoneBook.ContainsKey(name))
    {
        printValue = name + "=" + phoneBook[name];
    }

    Console.WriteLine(printValue);

    name = Console.ReadLine();

}while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name));
```

Since there is *Unknow*.i.e. You will then be given an unknown number of names to query your phone book for.